# How to read/write id3 tags in php 7?

Tags: php, php-7, pear, pecl, id3

There is a list of functions for id3 http://php.net/manual/ref.id3.php. It requires pecl package http://pecl.php.net/package/id3. Both versions of that package is alpha, but that is not the main problem.

**pear/id3 requires PHP (version >= 4.3.0, version <= 6.0.0), installed version is 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1**

How can I read and write ID3 tags in PHP 7?

Comment: This question is a bit off-topic for SO but I'd do a [search for ID3 libraries on Packagist](https://packagist.org/?query=id3) - looks like there are a few more current libraries to investigate there :)

Answer (score 2):

I faced with the same problem, after some searching I stopped on https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3

```
<?php

require 'vendor/getID3/getid3/getid3.php';

// Initialize getID3 engine
$getID3 = new getID3;

// Analyze file and store returned data in $ThisFileInfo
$ThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze('some mp3 file.mp3');

print_r($ThisFileInfo);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to compile with PECL: http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/id3/

I suggest using FFMPEG.

You can use FFmpeg with exec function.
https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/FFmpeg_Metadata

```
exec('ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c copy -metadata artist="Someone" output.mp3');
```

or http://eyed3.nicfit.net/ & etc.

```
var_dump(shell_exec("eyeD3 song.mp3 | grep artist"));
```

If your server is windows you can download & install a binary version of FFMPEG & then add FFMPEG location to your windows environment variables & reboot your system for working with FFMPEG on command prompt & shell_exec working with FFmpeg.